# Как собрать данные с сайтов за самый короткий промежуток времени

Tags: python, requests

Толком в интернете не нашёл никакого способа быстро собрать информацию c сайтов.
У меня есть 20000 url и надо за самый короткий промежуток времени собрать цены с сайта.
Выходит, что через requests выходит на 100 страниц 240 секунд, grequests 190 секунд.
Можно ли как-то укоротить это время раз так-то в 10.
counts=176321160,176288467,175966708,176042493...

```
import time
import grequests
import json
import re
import openpyxl
import datetime
import random

urls=[]

xlsx = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename='list8.0.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = xlsx.active
num, item2= 2, 2
i=1
try:
    for main in range(102,2102,100):
        t1me=time.time()
        urls.clear()
        for url in range(main-100,main):
            counts=sheet['G'+str(item2)].value
            urls.append(f"https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=RU&language=russian&currency=5&item_nameid={counts}&two_factor=0")
            item2 +=1
        responce=[grequests.get(u) for u in urls]
        maps=grequests.map(responce)
        print(round(time.time()-t1me,2),maps)
        for count in maps:
            t0=time.time()
            js = json.loads(count.text)
            order_price = quantily = normal_price = margin = difference =  None
            if 'buy_order_graph' in js:
                order_price = js.get('buy_order_graph')[0][0]
            if 'sell_order_summary' in js:
                quantily = int(str(re.findall("\d+", js.get('sell_order_summary'))[0]).replace("{'", '').replace("'}", ''))
            if 'sell_order_graph' in js:
                normal_price = float(js.get('sell_order_graph')[0][0])
            if order_price != None or normal_price != None:
                margin = str(round(((normal_price * 0.87 / order_price) - 1) * 100, 2))
                difference = str(round((normal_price) * 0.87 - order_price, 2))
            i+=1
            sheet['C' + str(num)] = str(normal_price)
            sheet['D' + str(num)] = str(order_price)
            sheet['E' + str(num)] = margin
            sheet['F' + str(num)] = difference
            sheet['H' + str(num)] = quantily
            sheet['I' + str(num)]= datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            xlsx.save('list8.0.xlsx')
            num+=1
            print(f'{i - 1}->{i} -- {order_price} -- {normal_price} -- {quantily} -- {margin} -- {difference} -- {round(time.time() - t0, 2)}')

except KeyboardInterrupt as Key:
    print('Keyboardinterrupt')
    xlsx.save('list8.0.xlsx')
    xlsx.close()

finally:
    xlsx.save('list8.0.xlsx')
    xlsx.close()
```

```
import openpyxl
import requests
import json
import re
import time
import datetime


xlsx = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename='list8.0.xlsx',data_only=True)
sheet = xlsx.active

try:
    i = 1
    for Item in range(2,102):
        t0 = time.time()
        sheet = xlsx.active
        url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=RU&language=russian&currency=5&item_nameid=' + str(sheet["G"+str(Item)].value) + '&two_factor=1'
        r=requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code==200:
            js=json.loads(r.text)
            order_price = quantily = normal_price = margin = difference = None
            if 'buy_order_graph' in js:
                order_price = js.get('buy_order_graph')[0][0]
            if 'sell_order_summary' in js:
                quantily = int(str(re.findall("\d+", js.get('sell_order_summary'))[0]).replace("{'", '').replace("'}", ''))
            if 'sell_order_graph' in js:
                normal_price = float(js.get('sell_order_graph')[0][0])
            if order_price != None or normal_price != None:
                margin = str(round(((normal_price * 0.87 / order_price) - 1)*100,2)) + '%'
                difference = str(round((normal_price) * 0.87 - order_price, 2)) + '₽'
            i+=1
            sheet['C'+str(Item)]=str(normal_price) + str('₽')
            sheet['D'+str(Item)]=str(order_price) + str('₽')
            sheet['E'+str(Item)]=margin
            sheet['F'+str(Item)]=difference
            sheet['H' + str(Item)] = quantily
            sheet['I' + str(Item)]= datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            xlsx.save('list8.0.xlsx')
            print(f'{i - 1}->{i}={round(time.time() - t0,2)} -- {order_price} -- {normal_price} -- {quantily} -- {margin} -- {difference}')
        else:
            print('!!!ERROR!!!')
            time.sleep(3)
            xlsx.save('')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    xlsx.save('list8.0.xlsx')
    xlsx.close()
finally:
    xlsx.save('list8.0.xlsx')
    xlsx.close()
```

Comment: Распараллель задачу, создай несколько потоков и в каждый поток передай часть ссылок

Comment: Я не думаю, что это сильно поможет, так как самая медленная операция это загрузка из интернет.

Comment: Поможет, так же работает и grequests. Он распараллеливает запросы. Пробуйте юзать grequests но разделив на два скрипта, запуская их отдельной.

Comment: @ProgerOffline, спасибо, видел, что у некоторых есть программы, которые собирают такие же данные менее чем за час (у меня же 9 часов на это выходит). Не знаете ли каким образом они это могут делать?

Comment: Запросы идут на один сервер?

Comment: @ProgerOffline, нет

Comment: Вот пользуйтесь тем способом который я описал выше. Делаете несколько скриптов на основе grequests, и запускайте их одновременно.

Comment: @ProgerOffline т.е. только через многопоточность можно это ускорить (не считая более хорошего интернета)?

Comment: Ну да, как думаешь на сколько измениться время если ты будешь отсылать на секунду не 5 запросов а 10?

Comment: @ProgerOffline, понял, спасибо